# What is the difference between these two statements?

Tags: past-participles

1. Coming to the theatre, I saw a gigantic crowd in front of the entrance.
2. Having come to the theatre, I saw a gigantic crowd in front of the entrance.

Comment: When did you notice the crowd?  As you arrived, or after you had gotten in line?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two sentences is the order in which the actions take place. In the first sentence, both the actions are taking place at the same time. It is the same as this:

> While coming to the theatre, I saw a gigantic crowd in front of the entrance.

It means that the action of noticing a crowd is taking place when the action of going to theatre is still being carried out. On the other hand, in the second sentence, actions take place in sequence - one after the other. This means that it is after the end of the first action that the second action takes place.